# Lombok not working with Android Studio 3.4

Tags: lombok, annotation-processing, android-studio-3.4, android-gradle-3.4.0

After updating android studio to 3.4, am facing issues with lombok plugin. Though inside model class, annotations are recognised and showing properly, in activity all getter and setter functions i have used, are not recognised.
I can build project as well, but in all activities all getter and setter functions are showing in red color. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried enabling annotation processor for android-studio. I am using lombok as dependency as given in the website, with annotation processor. Gradle version is 3.4.0.

Answer (score 7):

Enable Annotation Processing in Android Studio 3.4
1. Android Studio - File - Close Project
2. Configure - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Compiler - Annotation Processors - Enable annotation processing.

[image]

3. Open Project - Build - Rebuild Project.

Comment: how to enable in android studio 4.1  ?

Answer (score 3):

For me, i didn't install the plugin. That's why i think android studio was not able to recognise annotations but i was able to build the project.
I end up putting dependency in gradle file and installing the plugin through settings and now everything is working!

Answer (score 1):

If annotation processor is already enabled (Configure - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Compiler - Annotation Processors - Enable annotation processing) and even after restarting the system, lombok doesn't work, then just uninstall lombok plugin, re-install it and restart the android ide.

```
UnInstall: File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Installed --> select Lombok --> Select uninstall from drop down (top right corner)

Install: File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Marketplace --> serach Lombok --> click install --> restart android IDE
```

[image: UN-Installing plugin]

[image]

[image: Installing plugin:]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with Android Studio 3.6.1.

- 1) enable annotation processing (same as other answers here)
- 2) check versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle vs org.projectlombok:lombok

Lombok

```
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12"
    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12"
    kapt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```

This combination worked for me:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

This not:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
```